# how to use custom fonts on textview in android

Tags: android

For implementing custom font i seen few examples here issue is different,I am taking custom font in one abstract class which is used in all over the application.i am unable to change the fonts.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Check https://futurestud.io/tutorials/custom-fonts-on-android-extending-textview

Answer (score 4):

Create the custom class like below.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);

    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs!=null) {
             TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView);
             String fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomTextView_fontName);
             if (fontName!=null) {
                 Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/"+fontName);
                 setTypeface(myTypeface);
             }
             a.recycle();
        }
    }

}
```

and add your font in assets>fonts folder.

add following in attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomTextView">
        <attr name="fontName" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

to use.

```
<com.abc.cusomclass.CustomTextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    app:fontName="/*name of your font from assets/font folder*/"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this.
You have to add your .tff file on the assets folder

ArialMTBoldRegularTextView.java:

```
public final class ArialMTBoldRegularTextView extends CustomTextView {

    public static final String FONT_PATH = "arial-rounded-mt-bold.ttf";

    public ArialMTBoldRegularTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFont(FONT_PATH);
    }

    public ArialMTBoldRegularTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        setFont(FONT_PATH);
    }

    public ArialMTBoldRegularTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr);
        setFont(FONT_PATH);
    }

    public void setFont(String fontPath) {
        changeFont(this, fontPath);
    }



public static void changeFont(final CompoundButton button, final String fontPath) {
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(button.getContext().getAssets(), fontPath);
    button.setTypeface(typeface);
}
}
```

CustomTextView.java

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public Typeface getFont(final Context context, final String fontPath) {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontPath);
    }

    public void changeFont(final TextView textView, final String fontPath) {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(textView.getContext().getAssets(), fontPath);
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);
    }

    public void changeFont(final CompoundButton button, final String fontPath) {
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(button.getContext().getAssets(), fontPath);
        button.setTypeface(typeface);
    }
}
```

and fater in xml:

```
<packagename.views.ArialMTBoldRegularTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Pseudo"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this for custom font fron Assets

```
// Font path
        String fontPath = "fonts/Face Your Fears.ttf";

        // text view label
        TextView txtGhost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ghost);

        // Loading Font Face
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

        // Applying font
        txtGhost.setTypeface(tf);
```

for more information check this,
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-using-external-fonts/

Answer (score 1):

now android Support Library 26 supports using fonts directly from your XML see the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The better way of doing this is to make custom TextView with custom font like this:

**Java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class RegularProximaTextView extends TextView {
   public static Typeface FONT_NAME;


   public RegularProximaTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    if(FONT_NAME == null) FONT_NAME = 
  Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Mark Simonson - 
  Proxima Nova Regular.otf");
    this.setTypeface(FONT_NAME);
  }
  public RegularProximaTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
     if(FONT_NAME == null) FONT_NAME = 
    Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Mark Simonson - 
      Proxima 
      Nova Regular.otf");
      this.setTypeface(FONT_NAME);
   }
  public RegularProximaTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int 
  defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    if(FONT_NAME == null) FONT_NAME = 
       Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Mark Simonson - 
       Proxima Nova Regular.otf");
       this.setTypeface(FONT_NAME);
    }
 }
```

**XML**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/activity_login"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
  android:background="@color/colorGreyBar"
 >


   <com.tracer.joblogic.v2.helpers.custom_ui.RegularProximaTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="@color/colorButtonRed"
            android:text="Some text"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            />
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```